# Question on how to solve into spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

I am confused on how to convert $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ into spherical coordinates. I know that we have to use the formulas given, but I'm unsure how to solve since $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and not what the question asks.

Answer (score 1):

Taking one specific convention for spherical coordinates:

$$x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi \;\; \text{ and } \;\; y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

with $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$.

Substituting into $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, you will obtain $r\sin\theta$.